# MVC model View controller issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

> This is MoviesController.cs file .I have created a object for Movie model,it Contain Name and Id property and atlast created a list to display the objects to View.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;
namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {

        // GET: Movies
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Movie customer = new Movie();
            customer.Name = "Avengers";
            customer.Id = 01;
            Movie customer2 = new Movie();
            customer2.Name = "Age of ultron";
            customer2.Id = 02;
            Movie customer1 = new Movie();
            customer1.Name = "amazing spiderman";
            customer1.Id = 03;
            Movie customer3 = new Movie();
            customer1.Name = "spiderman noway home";
            customer1.Id = 04;
            List<Movie> list = new List<Movie>();
            list.Add(customer);
            list.Add(customer1);
            list.Add(customer2);
            list.Add(customer3);
            return View(list);
        }
        
    }
}
```

this is Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Movies</h1>

@foreach (var mov in Model)
{
    <h3>@mov.Name</h3>
    <h3>@mov.Id</h3>
}
```

Movies
Avengers
1
spiderman noway home
4
Age of ultron
2
0
Could not able to fetch amazing spiderman value and for ID. It return zero why??

Comment: Is there a problem with this block: 
```Movie customer3 = new Movie(); customer1.Name = "spiderman noway home"; customer1.Id = 04; ```     

Should it be: ```Movie customer3 = new Movie(); customer3.Name = "spiderman noway home"; customer3.Id = 04 ```

Comment: Because you overwrite `customer1` instead of adding the properties to `customer3`?